# Can an iphone app process audio input while the phone is in sleep mode

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to build an app that can take in a user audio input and process it even if the phone is in sleep mode. For example, if a user says "Hello", then app needs to recognize that and process it even if the phone is in sleep mode. I have read posts that explain how to prevent a phone from going into sleep mode and that would be my second option if the app cannot read the audio input while the phone is in sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible, there are 5 different types of apps that can keep on running on the background, these are (from the Apple documentation):

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

if your app is not doing any of these, your app will not execute code when it goes onto the background. Also, you should declare that your app is performing one of these functions before sending it to Apple for review.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that case, do you know if an app can detect that the phone is about to go into sleep mode, either automatically via the auto-lock or when someone manually puts the phone in sleep more, and display a warning message on the screen or an audio alert to the user. Basically if my app is about to stop working because the phone will be going in sleep mode, then I would like to alert the user about it.